# Converting 17 to "2017", SQL

Tags: ms-access

**BACKGROUND**

I currently have two tables:

- `ActualSale.Year` = "2017"

  - Note the text format
- `BudgetSale.Year` = 17

  - Note the number format

I am looking to combine data from the `ActualSale` table and the `BudgetSales` table and join them on the `year` field.

**APPROACH/PSEUDO CODE**

```
SELECT
ActualSale.Year,
BudgetSales.Year

FROM
BudgetSale,
ActualSale

WHERE
ActualSales.year="2017"
```

*NOTE: Budget Sales tables are only inputted year-by-year, therefore the `BudgetSale` table only has data where `year`=17 (therefore, I do not necessarily have to filter for `BudgetSales.Year=17`.*

**QUESTIONS**

1. Within SQL, how can I consistently convert "2017" (text) to 17 (number). I was thinking of removing the first two numbers in `ActualSales.year` to just leave "17" and then convert to a value using `val()`, but was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Is this MySQL or Access? You've used both tags, but I wouldn't be surprised if the best answers were different. Is there any reason you can't change the schema here? (I would expect the year field to be an integer field, but with the value 2017... neither "2017" nor 17 seem good to me.)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot directly change the schema as the tables are Views from our production database. I suppose I could pull in all the information and transform the table, but I'd like to keep this as lean as possible.

Comment: `WHERE Cint(Right(ActualSales.year,2)) = BudgetSales.Year` - That should be 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering whether to answer - as Jon Skeet has given a comment I suspect that SQL has rewritten itself to conform.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9182#9182

The first problem is that `Year` is a reserved word (has a specific meaning to Access).

One way to solve the problem is to add 2000 to the BudgetSale year.
This will be a problem if you're dealing with dates pre-2000.

```
FROM ActualSale ASa INNER JOIN BudgetSale BSa ON CLNG(ASa.sYear)=BSa.lYear+2000
```

Another way as you suggest is to remove the first two numbers from the string:

```
FROM ActualSale ASa INNER JOIN BudgetSale BSa ON VAL(right(ASa.sYear,2))=BSa.lYear
```

Another way is to convert the Years into dates:

```
FROM ActualSale ASa INNER JOIN BudgetSale BSa ON Year(DateSerial(ASa.syear,1,1))=Year(DateSerial(BSa.lyear,1,1))
```

*I think the best way is to convert the values to dates before they're added to the database.*

Answer (score 0):

In mySQL you will need to setup a join between the two tables, IOW, how are they related.

```
SELECT
    ActualSale.Year,
    BudgetSales.Year
FROM BudgetSale
JOIN ActualSale
    ON ActualSales.year = CONCAT("20",BudgetSales.Year)
WHERE ActualSales.year="2017"
```

You will need to specify a bit more in the ON clause, since all of the year values are the same, every record in the ActualSale. will match with every record in the BudgetSale table.

Answer (score 0):

`CInt(ActualSale.Year)-2000` will do what you want without much fuss.

In case your database is old enough to have pre-2000 years, use IIF to check for that:

`CInt(ActualSale.Year)-IIF(CInt(ActualSale.Year)<2000,1900,2000)`